# BSD Virtual Private Servers

Tags: bsd

I know of a couple of VPS providers that support BSD distros (rootbsd and prgmr), but I'm wondering if anyone has any other solutions they'd recommend? Moreover, I'm very curious why BSD support in the VPS world has been lagging behind Linux. I know the supply/demand may be different for each, but is there a technical reason that it's slow to adoption?

Comment: You should ask one answerable question, see also the FAQ. http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, BSD VPS providers seem pretty few & far between.  Here are a couple I've found that provide FreeBSD:

- [CloudSigma](http://cloudsigma.com)
- [AYK Solutions - Provides FreeBSD option for cloud servers](http://ayksolutions.com)

It seems like there probably isn't as much demand for BSD based servers right now... but perhaps that will change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

## Digital Ocean

[DigitalOcean.com](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) is a major vendor of virtual servers.

In early 2015, the company launched a major revamp of their architecture to support [FreeBSD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) VMs as well as their previous Linux VMs.

See their [blog post announcement](https://www.digitalocean.com/company/blog/presenting-freebsd-how-we-made-it-happen/) for details.